# PHP Rest API to Receive Image from iOS App

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I'm brand new to iOS development, and am presently working on an iOS app where I need to send an image I have in iOS to a rest API written in PHP. Below is what my request to send the image to the PHP server looks like in iOS:

```
- (void)uploadImage {
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.private.com/uploadimage.php";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:5.0f];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView.image, 0.3f);
    [[session uploadTaskWithRequest:urlRequest fromData:imageData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }
    }] resume];

  }
```

Before we proceed, does that look right? If it is right, what PHP code can I write to receive the image being sent and then upload it to some specified folder? I've looked around, but I haven't found any PHP ones that deal with iOS's NSURLSession.

Comment: You are doing this backwards. Write a PHP page that can process file uploads (a quick search will point you to many examples). Nothing about the PHP page will be specific to being used by an iOS app. It should work for any client written for any platform. When that is done, then write the code for your iOS app to upload the image using the page your wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example photo upload php code;

```
function multiProfileUpload_($target_dir,$files,$user_id)
{
for($i=0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $filename = uniqid();
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($files["fileToUpload"]["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $target_file = $target_dir . $filename.".".$imageFileType;
    $name=$filename.".".$imageFileType;

    move_uploaded_file($files["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
    $profile_pic = BASE_PATH.$target_dir.$name;
    $query = "UPDATE user_profile SET profile_pic = '$profile_pic' where user_id = $user_id;";
    mysql_query($query);
    $result['status'] = "success";
    $result['path'] = $profile_pic;
}
return $result;
}
```

And Api entry point should be look something like this;

```
if(@$_REQUEST['apiEntry']=="update_profile_image")
{
    if(!isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']) ||$_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE)
    {
        $data['status'] = "error";
        $data['message'] = "Error on uploading files";
    }else
    {
        $data = multiProfileUpload_("images/profile/",$_FILES,$_REQUEST['user_id']);
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

It will be much convenient to use 3rd party libraries for network connections rather than NSURLConnection itself while they are all based on it. Example is using [AFNetworking v2.0](https://cocoapods.org/pods/AFNetworking)

```
- (void)updateProfileImage{
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   self.user_id,   @"user_id",
                                   nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] init];
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;//This is for https
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?apiEntry=update_profile_image",BASE_URL] parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgView.image, 1.0f) name:@"fileToUpload" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@",operation.request);
    NSDictionary *responseJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",responseJson);
    if ([[responseJson objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"success"]) {
        //do something
    }else{
        //do some other thing
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}];
```

}

Comment: I was hoping to use the NSURLSession just to get some practice, so is it better to just use the AFNetworking then?

Comment: Definitely better, and you could study from AFNetworking how NSURLConnection is being used there

Comment: One other question, can I have multiple requests be made from the AFNetworking class? Or is it just one per file? (not going to do this, just curious)

Comment: You can do multiple files using AFNetworking, and also could do multiple request as well as they have operation queue. In case you use queue, you don't need to modify PHP side, but in case you do multiple files in one request, need to modify PHP a bit, current one is not perfect for multiple upload

Comment: Also, I'm slightly confused by how the $_FILES contains the specific information?

Comment: For some reason, sharedClient isn't coming up as an available method for the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager. Any idea why?

Comment: Why is there an @ before the $_REQUEST ?